# App crashed due to memory pressure

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks, cgcontext

Here I am generating images of UIViews and for that I am using the following code:

```
    // ======================== Create PDF FROM Images     ============================

- (void) drawBorder
{
    CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIColor *borderColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    CGRect rectFrame = CGRectMake(kBorderInset, kBorderInset, pageSize.width-kBorderInset*2, pageSize.height-kBorderInset*2);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(currentContext, borderColor.CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(currentContext, kBorderWidth);
    CGContextStrokeRect(currentContext, rectFrame);

    //CGContextRelease(currentContext);
}

- (void)drawPageNumber:(NSInteger)pageNumber
{
    NSString* pageNumberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page %d", pageNumber];
    UIFont* theFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];

    CGSize pageNumberStringSize = [pageNumberString sizeWithFont:theFont
                                               constrainedToSize:pageSize
                                                   lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    CGRect stringRenderingRect = CGRectMake(kBorderInset,
                                            pageSize.height - 40.0,
                                            pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset,
                                            pageNumberStringSize.height);

    [pageNumberString drawInRect:stringRenderingRect withFont:theFont lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
}

- (void) drawHeader:(int)i;
{
    CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    //CGContextSetRGBFillColor(currentContext, 0.3, 0.7, 0.2, 1.0);

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(currentContext, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1);

    //NSString *textToDraw = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@ \n\nDate Range: %@ \n\nNumber of observations: %@",appDelegate.teacherName,@"Curriculum report",lblDate.text,lblNoOf.text];
    NSString *textToDraw;

    if(i<[arrReportTitles count])
        textToDraw=[arrReportTitles objectAtIndex:i];

    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];

    CGSize stringSize = [textToDraw sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset-2*kMarginInset, pageSize.height - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    CGRect renderingRect = CGRectMake(kBorderInset + kMarginInset, kBorderInset + kMarginInset, pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset, stringSize.height);

    [textToDraw drawInRect:renderingRect withFont:font lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];

    //CGContextRelease(currentContext);
}

- (void) drawText
{
    CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(currentContext, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    NSString *textToDraw = @"TeachersEvaluation";
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24.0];
    CGSize stringSize = [textToDraw sizeWithFont:font
                               constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset-2*kMarginInset, pageSize.height - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset)
                                   lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    CGRect renderingRect = CGRectMake(kBorderInset + kMarginInset + 375, kBorderInset + kMarginInset + 450.0, pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset, stringSize.height-50);
    [textToDraw drawInRect:renderingRect
                  withFont:font
             lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping
                 alignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];

    //CGContextRelease(currentContext);
}

- (void) drawLine
{
    CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(currentContext, kLineWidth);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(currentContext, [UIColor grayColor].CGColor);

    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(kMarginInset + kBorderInset, kMarginInset + kBorderInset + 120.0);
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(pageSize.width - 2*kMarginInset -2*kBorderInset, kMarginInset + kBorderInset + 120.0);

    CGContextBeginPath(currentContext);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(currentContext, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(currentContext, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);

    CGContextClosePath(currentContext);
    CGContextDrawPath(currentContext, kCGPathFillStroke);

    //CGContextRelease(currentContext);
}

-(NSInteger) getImageHeighAndWidht : (NSInteger) value
{
    value = value / 2;

    if (value > 800 ) {

        [self getImageHeighAndWidht:value];

    }

    if (value<450) {

        value = value + (value/2);

    }

    return value;
}

- (void) drawImage: (UIImage *)fileName
{
    CGSize mainImageSize;
    UIImage *mainImage;

    if (fileName.size.width > 542 || fileName.size.height > 742)
    {
        if (fileName.size.height > fileName.size.width) {

            mainImageSize = CGSizeMake(470,575);
            mainImage =fileName; //[fileName scaleProportionalToSize:mainImageSize];

        } else {

            mainImageSize = CGSizeMake(290,395);
            mainImage = fileName;//[fileName scaleProportionalToSize:mainImageSize];

        }

    } else {

        mainImageSize = CGSizeMake(fileName.size.width,fileName.size.height);
        mainImage =fileName; //[fileName scaleProportionalToSize:mainImageSize];
    }

    float imageWidht;
    if (mainImage.size.width > 542)
    {
        imageWidht = 542;
    } else {
        imageWidht = mainImage.size.width;
    }

    float imageHeight;
    if (mainImage.size.height > 575)
    {
        imageHeight = 600.0;
    } else {
        imageHeight = mainImage.size.height;
    }

    //UIImage * demoImage = [UIImage imageNamed:fileName];
    [mainImage drawInRect:CGRectMake( (pageSize.width - imageWidht)/2, 150, imageWidht, imageHeight)];
}

- (void) generatePdfWithFilePath: (NSString *)thefilePath
{
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(thefilePath, CGRectZero, nil);

    NSInteger currentPage = 0;

//    _imgViewScreenShot.image=[arrMultiplePhots objectAtIndex:0];
//    _imgViewScreenShot2.image=[arrMultiplePhots objectAtIndex:1];


    for(int i = 0; i < [arrMultiplePhots count]; i++){

        //Start a new page.
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), nil);

        //Draw a page number at the bottom of each page.
        currentPage++;
        [self drawPageNumber:currentPage];

        //Draw a border for each page.
        [self drawBorder];

        //Draw text fo our header.
        [self drawHeader:i];

        //Draw a line below the header.
        [self drawLine];

        //if(i == 0) {
        //currImage = [self.view imageByRenderingView];

        //_imgViewScreenShot.image=currImage;
        [self drawImage:[arrMultiplePhots objectAtIndex:i]];
        //}
    }

    // Close the PDF context and write the contents out.
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
}
```

But when I generate images for multiple views continuously inside a loop, my app crashes with a warning "App crashed due to memory pressure".

I used the instruments tool to find out the reason behind this crash and there I got memory leak warnings around all these functions.

So how to solve this memory leak issue in the above code?

EDIT

after using autorelease memory leaks are removed in above functions

now I am getting memory leaks in this function

which generate image

```
- (UIImage *)imageByRenderingView
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return resultingImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this change and tell me if it helps:

```
- (void) generatePdfWithFilePath: (NSString *)thefilePath
{
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(thefilePath, CGRectZero, nil);

    NSInteger currentPage = 0;

//    _imgViewScreenShot.image=[arrMultiplePhots objectAtIndex:0];
//    _imgViewScreenShot2.image=[arrMultiplePhots objectAtIndex:1];


    for(int i = 0; i < [arrMultiplePhots count]; i++)
    {
        @autoreleasepool {
            //Start a new page.
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), nil);

            //Draw a page number at the bottom of each page.
            currentPage++;
            [self drawPageNumber:currentPage];

            //Draw a border for each page.
            [self drawBorder];

            //Draw text fo our header.
            [self drawHeader:i];

            //Draw a line below the header.
            [self drawLine];

            //if(i == 0) {
            //currImage = [self.view imageByRenderingView];

            //_imgViewScreenShot.image=currImage;
            [self drawImage:[arrMultiplePhots objectAtIndex:i]];
            //}
        }
    }

    // Close the PDF context and write the contents out.
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
}
```

Comment: hey sorry for late reply and thanks for your help. After using autorelease memory leaks are removed in above functions
But now I am getting memory leaks in one new function which I have added in my question under EDIT tag.

Comment: Well, you should wrap the call to that method with an "@autoreleasepool" too.